# How can I strictly add a Spring HttpMessageConverter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC controller that uses a heavily configured Jackson mapper to convert a POST body from an external service into a Java object. Since this controller is an embeddable component, the mapper is only used for this specific data type, and I have an `HttpMessageConverter` that handles the conversion correctly.

However, I'm having trouble wiring this converter into the Web MVC configuration without stomping on the configuration for the main application this controller is embedded in. I've tried `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, but unlike `addFormatters`, which allows me to append custom formatters, any converter added in `configureMessageConverters` prevents Spring from adding the default converter set; there doesn't appear to be any analog of the XML `register-defaults` options.

What's the cleanest way for an add-in component to register its own custom `HttpMessageConverter` without interfering with the conversion service for the rest of the application?

Comment: I don't have time to dig, but you might be able to retrieve the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` bean and use its `getMessageConverter` method to retrieve and inject a `HttpMessageConverter`. I'm just not sure if, by that time, the returned `List` has already been copied/used in other components.

Comment: That's the approach I'm currently working on, but at this point it's not looking like it's working. I'm even having trouble getting breakpoints working inside the mapping system.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fragile solution and I would welcome more robust alternatives, but I have the basic functionality working thus:

The `List<HttpMessageConverter<?>>` used by the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` is referenced, but not defensively copied, elsewhere in the Spring MVC architecture. Obtaining a reference to the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` in a bean and manually calling

```
rhma.getMessageConverters.add(0, myConverter);
```

works, but this depends on the internal behavior of a number of separate components.

Answer (score 0):

HttpMessageConverters can be configured per servlet. If you add an additional dispatcher servlet to `web.xml` you can configure `HttpMessageConverters` for this servlet separately.

web.xml:

```
...
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>custom</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
...
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>custom</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/custom/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
```

custom-servlet.xml:

```
<beans>
  <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
      <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"/>
    </mvc:message-converters>
  </mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
  <context:component-scan base-package="package.containing.custom.controller" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
  </context:component-scan>
</beans>
```